# How do I properly use unordered_map?

Tags: string, unordered-map

I'm writing a program that is supposed to count amount of times a string 3 characters long appears.  I have a loop that makes substrings of 3 characters from a larger string, but when I try to insert them into an unordered_map, I get a bunch of errors.  What am I doing wrong?

```
int a =0;

std::string subs= "";

std::unordered_map <std::string,int> mapp = {};
int count=0;

for(int i=0; i<ss.length(); i++){

subs= ss.substr(a,k);
if(subs.length()<k){
   return -1;
}
    std::cout << "Substring: " << subs << std::endl;
    a++;
    mapp.insert(std::make_pair<std::string,int>(subs,count));

  }
```

Comment: Perhaps [reading the documentation of `std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) rather than guessing at the parameters of its member functions will help. There is no match to what you're doing for the [`insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert) method.

Comment: @WhozCraig Oops! I didn't change the updated insert line before posting.  The way I have it, assuming I understand correctly, is that it inserts only the first substring.  So I guess to specify my question, I'm looking to find out how to iterate through the rest of the substrings.